# can't create multiple internal load balancer within deployment?

Tags: azure

I have azure subscription with one VNet and it has one cloud service.
When I try to create 2nd internal load balancer for set of VMs, I get error

> Add-AzureInternalLoadBalancer : BadRequest: LoadBalancer already exists: MarvelILB. Only one internal load balancer allowed per deployment.

Is this documented anywhere?
I don't understand why this restriction exists because i first create internal load balancer(ILB) and then associate it with a load balance set, so one ILB is applied to specific machines, not to the entire cloud service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to review the concepts behind what a Cloud Service is in the context of Azure VMs.

If you want to have a separate ILB for a separate set of VMs then they should all live in another Cloud Service.

A Cloud Service is just a logical container for a group of VMs that allows you present them as a single unit and provide load balancing and access control for them.  I'd typically see one Cloud Service per Server Role in an architecture as working best.

Answer (score 0):

A single internal load balancer can handle multiple load balanced sets. So, just like with the external load balancer (the one that you can manage via the portal), you can create multiple load balanced sets that contain endpoints on different sets of VMs within the cloud service.